# Ubuntu 16.04 won't connect to wifi

Tags: 16.04, wireless, ralink

I had Ubuntu for a few month and nothing was going wrong until now. When I try to connect it takes a long time then disconnect me. I'd try `sudo service network-manager restart` where a bunch of other sites told me that it would be a temporary solution but nothing happened. My laptop loss connection every time I closed it but that didn't bothered me the problem started when I open the laptop and realize that the wifi was connecting so I reboot into windows and play a game but when I got back to Ubuntu it wasn't still connecting.

Info

```
*-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RT5390 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
       vendor: Ralink corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 00
       serial: 9c:d2:1e:8a:b2:b6
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800pci driverversion=4.4.14-040414-generic firmware=0.34 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:17 memory:f7d00000-f7d0ffff
```

Update 2

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 20 Jul 2017 19:31 EDT -0400

Booted last: 20 Jul 2017 00:00 EDT -0400

Script from: 25 Mar 2017 07:04 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.4.14-040414-generic #201606241434 SMP Fri Jun 24 18:36:45 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:635 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf line 1: ignoring bad line starting with 'option'

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT5390 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:5390]
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. RT5390 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [105b:e054]
    Kernel driver in use: rt2800pci

03:00.2 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 06)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [1043:200f]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b404 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c52f Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

asus_nb_wmi            24576  0
asus_wmi               28672  1 asus_nb_wmi
sparse_keymap          16384  1 asus_wmi
rt2800pci              16384  0
rt2800mmio             20480  1 rt2800pci
rt2800lib              94208  2 rt2800pci,rt2800mmio
rt2x00pci              16384  1 rt2800pci
rt2x00mmio             16384  2 rt2800pci,rt2800mmio
rt2x00lib              57344  5 rt2x00pci,rt2800lib,rt2800pci,rt2800mmio,rt2x00mmio
mac80211              737280  3 rt2x00lib,rt2x00pci,rt2800lib
cfg80211              565248  2 mac80211,rt2x00lib
eeprom_93cx6           16384  1 rt2800pci
crc_ccitt              16384  1 rt2800lib
wmi                    20480  1 asus_wmi
video                  40960  2 i915,asus_wmi

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

enp3s0f2  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'enp3s0f2' [IF1]>  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1780 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1780 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:132032 (132.0 KB)  TX bytes:132032 (132.0 KB)

wlp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'wlp2s0' [IF2]>  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp3s0f2  no wireless extensions.

wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off


##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface

##### resolv.conf #######################

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       807     1  0 19:26 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlp2s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Ralink corp.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RT5390 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         rt2800pci
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 4.4.14-040414-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               N/A
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'wlp2s0' [IF2]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            0
GENERAL.STATE:                          30 (disconnected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:02:00.0/net/wlp2s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:                   no
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{1}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   abcee2e1-a48d-4b4e-a97a-a36db4b3a202 | dlink-F3BF 1

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp3s0f2
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 2.3LK-NAPI
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp3s0f2' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         2 (Device is now managed)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.3/0000:03:00.2/net/enp3s0f2
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: 

SSID                           BSSID              MODE   CHAN  FREQ      RATE       SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY   ACTIVE  * 
dlink-F3BF                     <MAC 'dlink-F3BF' [AN1]>  Infra  1     2412 MHz  54 Mbit/s  82      â–‚â–„â–†â–ˆ  WPA1 WPA2  no        
DIRECT-54-HP ENVY 7640 series  <MAC 'DIRECT-54-HP ENVY 7640 series' [AN2]>  Infra  6     2437 MHz  54 Mbit/s  59      â–‚â–„â–†_  WPA2       no        
Rogers75557                    <MAC 'Rogers75557' [AN3]>  Infra  9     2452 MHz  54 Mbit/s  55      â–‚â–„__  WPA1 WPA2  no        
Execulink193f                  <MAC 'Execulink193f' [AN4]>  Infra  11    2462 MHz  54 Mbit/s  49      â–‚â–„__  WPA2       no        
A6IIFR6C                       <MAC 'A6IIFR6C' [AN5]>  Infra  1     2412 MHz  54 Mbit/s  45      â–‚â–„__  WPA2       no        
TP-LINK_0383                   <MAC 'TP-LINK_0383' [AN6]>  Infra  1     2412 MHz  54 Mbit/s  45      â–‚â–„__  WPA1 WPA2  no        
Rogers82537                    <MAC 'Rogers82537' [AN7]>  Infra  6     2437 MHz  54 Mbit/s  45      â–‚â–„__  WPA1 WPA2  no        
Chunky Monkey                  <MAC 'Chunky Monkey' [AN8]>  Infra  11    2462 MHz  54 Mbit/s  42      â–‚â–„__  WPA1 WPA2  no        
Primus-0e61                    <MAC 'Primus-0e61' [AN9]>  Infra  6     2437 MHz  54 Mbit/s  39      â–‚â–„__  WPA1 WPA2  no        
BELL953                        <MAC 'BELL953' [AN10]>  Infra  6     2437 MHz  54 Mbit/s  39      â–‚â–„__  WPA2       no        
C4A0709C5AD1                   <MAC 'C4A0709C5AD1' [AN11]>  Infra  1     2412 MHz  54 Mbit/s  35      â–‚â–„__  WPA2       no        
--                             <MAC '--' [AN12]>  Infra  11    2462 MHz  54 Mbit/s  35      â–‚â–„__  WPA1 WPA2  no        
NETGEAR                        <MAC 'NETGEAR' [AN13]>  Infra  11    2462 MHz  54 Mbit/s  32      â–‚â–„__  WPA2       no        
RogersWifi                     <MAC 'RogersWifi' [AN14]>  Infra  1     2412 MHz  54 Mbit/s  29      â–‚___  WPA2       no        

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/dlink-F3BF 1]] (600 root)
[connection] id=dlink-F3BF 1 | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlp2s0' [IF2]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=dlink-F3BF
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/dlink-F3BF]] (600 root)
[connection] id=dlink-F3BF | type=wifi | permissions=user:ubuntu:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlp2s0' [IF2]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=dlink-F3BF
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: America/Toronto (based on set time zone)

country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, NO-IR
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

enp3s0f2  no frequency information.

wlp2s0    14 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 14 : 2.484 GHz

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp3s0f2  Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlp2s0    Interface doesn't support scanning : Device or resource busy

##### module infos ######################

[rt2800pci]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.14-040414-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rt2x00/rt2800pci.ko
license:        GPL
firmware:       rt2860.bin
description:    Ralink RT2800 PCI & PCMCIA Wireless LAN driver.
version:        2.3.0
author:         http://rt2x00.serialmonkey.com
srcversion:     26CCED9E0CE5EFBFA9B8882
depends:        rt2x00lib,rt2800lib,rt2800mmio,rt2x00mmio,rt2x00pci,eeprom_93cx6
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.14-040414-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           nohwcrypt:Disable hardware encryption. (bool)

[rt2800mmio]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.14-040414-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rt2x00/rt2800mmio.ko
license:        GPL
description:    rt2800 MMIO library
version:        2.3.0
author:         http://rt2x00.serialmonkey.com
srcversion:     01C1A7641505065E52E0388
depends:        rt2800lib,rt2x00lib,rt2x00mmio
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.14-040414-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 

[rt2800lib]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.14-040414-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rt2x00/rt2800lib.ko
license:        GPL
description:    Ralink RT2800 library
version:        2.3.0
author:         http://rt2x00.serialmonkey.com, Bartlomiej Zolnierkiewicz
srcversion:     BB9F48B63A82C3FD3E73BAF
depends:        rt2x00lib,mac80211,crc-ccitt
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.14-040414-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 

[rt2x00pci]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.14-040414-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rt2x00/rt2x00pci.ko
license:        GPL
description:    rt2x00 pci library
version:        2.3.0
author:         http://rt2x00.serialmonkey.com
srcversion:     543B84557258F153AC267F0
depends:        rt2x00lib,mac80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.14-040414-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 

[rt2x00mmio]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.14-040414-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rt2x00/rt2x00mmio.ko
license:        GPL
description:    rt2x00 mmio library
version:        2.3.0
author:         http://rt2x00.serialmonkey.com
srcversion:     ADBE279820CFD0A1081C682
depends:        rt2x00lib
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.14-040414-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 

[rt2x00lib]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.14-040414-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rt2x00/rt2x00lib.ko
license:        GPL
description:    rt2x00 library
version:        2.3.0
author:         http://rt2x00.serialmonkey.com
srcversion:     72E39180D883A5541F66494
depends:        mac80211,cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.14-040414-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.14-040414-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     2FFAEED0245CA1D97FE1E44
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.14-040414-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.14-040414-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     25A45701AAA64DAC1E47D9D
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.14-040414-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[rt2800pci]
nohwcrypt: N

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf]
option ath9k nohwcrypt=1

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

[/etc/modprobe.d/rt5390.conf]
options rt5390 fwlps=N

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

[/etc/pm/config.d/config] (644 root)
SUSPEND_MODULES = "rt5390"

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[   14.351040] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00_set_rt: Info - RT chipset 5390, rev 1502 detected
[   14.355283] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00_set_rf: Info - RF chipset 5390 detected
[   16.215884] rt2800pci 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
[   30.515475] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
[   30.515533] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00lib_request_firmware: Info - Loading firmware file 'rt2860.bin'
[   30.780571] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00lib_request_firmware: Info - Firmware detected - version: 0.34
[   30.905522] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
[   30.911647] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp3s0f2: link is not ready
[   31.123072] r8169 0000:03:00.2 enp3s0f2: link down
[   31.123132] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp3s0f2: link is not ready
[   31.839841] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready (repeated 2 times)

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: Can you expand on this a little? What hardware do you have, when did the problem start, did you upgrade anything or change anything that could have caused the problem, how are you connecting, and what do you do with `sudo service network-manager`

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please [run the network diagnostics](//askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result? I know it may seem a bit overwhelming for a novice but your info so far is a bit vague and the diagnostics will likely cover all options that may cause your issue. Thanks.